# Some irreducible complex representation of symmetric groups

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Consider the natural action of symmetric groups $S_n$ on $X_i\subset2^{N_n}$, where $N_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$, and $X_i=\{A=\{a_1,...,a_i\}|A\subset N_n\}$ (Basically they are just actions on indices). It induces complex representations of $S_n$ with dimension $\begin{pmatrix}n\\i\end{pmatrix}$, and their characters are denoted by $\chi_i$. We also denote the trivial representation as $\chi_0$. I want to show that $(\chi_i-\chi_{i-1}),1\leq i \leq [\frac{n}{2}]$ are $[\frac{n}{2}]$ irreducible complex representations of $S_n$ but I have got no idea how to prove it. At first I want to find a subspace of $V_i$ isomorphic to $V_{i-1}$, since it works for $i=1$ (Let $V=\{(x_1,...,x_n)|x_1=...=x_n\}\subset V_n$. Then dim$V=1$, and $V_n/V$ is irreducible, with character same as $(\chi_1-\chi_0)$), but it seems a difficult task for $i>1$...so maybe there is a better way to prove this. I think I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: if $\chi$ is an integer linear combination of irreps, then $\chi$ is the character of an irrep iff $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle = 1$ and $\chi(0)$ is positive.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've already tried this approach before, which just turned the problem into complex combinatorial identities...maybe you have some nice ideas for proving them?

Comment: Hint #2: if $\chi_X, \chi_Y$ are characters of representations obtained from a finite group $G$ acting on sets $X$ and $Y$, then $\langle \chi_X, \chi_Y \rangle$ is the number of orbits of the action of $G$ on $X \times Y$ .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan ...OK, I used your hint and it turned out to be the very approach I said in my first comment. As I mentioned above, it just turned the problem into complex combinatorial identities, and I have already tried many ways to count the orbits but made no progress...

Comment: I'll post a complete solution. No complex combinatorial identities are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that

$$\langle \chi_i - \chi_{i-1}, \chi_i - \chi_{i-1} \rangle = \langle \chi_i, \chi_i \rangle - 2 \langle \chi_i, \chi_{i-1} \rangle + \langle \chi_{i-1}, \chi_{i-1} \rangle = 1.$$

We'll show this using the fact I described in my comment above that if $\chi_X$ is the character of the permutation representation on a $G$-set $X$, then $\langle \chi_X, \chi_Y \rangle$ is the number of $G$-orbits of the action of $G$ on $X \times Y$. So it suffices to count the number of orbits of the action of $S_n$ on the set of pairs (a subset of $[n] = \{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$ of size $i$, a subset of size $j$), and then to plug in appropriate $i, j$.

I claim that up to the $S_n$ action, a pair of subsets $S, T$ of $[n]$ is determined by the size of its intersection $S \cap T$ and by the size of the complements $S \setminus (S \cap T), T \setminus (S \cap T)$. If the sizes $|S| = i, |T| = j$ are fixed then the only information is the size of the intersection, which can be anywhere from $0$ to $\text{min}(i, j)$. Hence the number of orbits is $\text{min}(i, j) + 1$. This gives

$$\langle \chi_i, \chi_i \rangle = i$$
$$\langle \chi_i, \chi_{i-1} \rangle = i - 1$$
$$\langle \chi_{i-1}, \chi_{i-1} \rangle = i - 1$$

so the inner product we want to compute is

$$i - 2 (i - 1) + (i - 1) = 1$$

as desired.

Comment: It's actually not much of a leap from here to writing a direct proof by finding a subrepresentation of $V_i$ isomorphic to $V_{i-1}$.

Comment: OK, thanks. Maybe I misunderstood your hint before, but your answer is clear. It really helps a lot.

Comment: Above I need $i, j \le \frac{n}{2}$, which is in the question but which I omitted to specify.